# Why can't I set up Coreos with Vagrant and VirtualBox on win7?

Tags: git, vagrant, containers, virtualbox, vmware

I was trying to install the vagrant distribution on Windows 7 for a single VM following these instructions [[1](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vagrant.html#single-machine)][[2](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant)], and, for additional information, as that was the URL the first link was referring to for downloading the package on prompt.

These was the commands I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant.git
cd coreos-vagrant
vagrant up
```

When executing the last command the prompt just hanged. After searching for meta-data for box, accessing Google APIs URL and adding box to the default provider, in case VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution, I ran the last line again, this time with  `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`. It seems that running the setup codes without specifying the provider of the VM somehow freezes it or the vagrant just was needing some reference for the setup as some links suggested, what was solved on a second install (I dont remember the links now but I will try to find on my browser history)